# Deleting rows based on values on multiple columns in R

Tags: r

I am using R and need to select rows based on information in various columns.

Sample data set is given below:

I am trying to remove rows based on following criteria of matching the Company, Product and MRP greater than equal to and MRP less than equal to particular numbers.

My code is as follows:

```
dplyr::filter(feb_raw, feb_raw$Company.=="STL" & 
                       feb_raw$Product.=="N24" & 
                       feb_raw$MRP<=1360 & feb_raw$MRP>=1150)
```

I want to have only those rows based on specific Company, Product and MRP range while keeping the rest of rows intact in the dataframe.

Any help in this regards will be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please add data using `dput` and show the expected output for the same. Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 2):

Your code looks almost correct. The `dplyr` package uses "non-standard evaluation" of its arguments, so the variables you use in those arguments are evaluated in an environment where *the columns of your dataframe are variables*.

tl;dr: you write it this way:

```
dplyr::filter(feb_raw, Company.=="STL" & 
                       Product.=="N24" & 
                       MRP<=1360 &
                       MRP>=1150)
```

Refer to the excellent [dplyr vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/dplyr.html) for more info.

Comment: Thanks for the support, but while executing above code the total rows in my dataset remains same, while I was expecting that it will remove / deleat rows based on the mentioned conditions from my dataset. Can you please help me in getting desired results. Thanks.

Comment: There are operations that mutate in place (that seems to be what you were expecting), but this is a function that _returns_ or _evaluates to_ the desired result. Run this code in your console to see the result, or assign the result to a variable and view that.

Comment: Also it's possible these statements (`Company.=="STL"` etc) are all true for all rows in your dataset and that's why the number of rows isn't changing. Who knows. Post some code to show what you tried.

Answer (score 0):

I simulated a dataset based upon your question by running:

```
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(1)

feb_raw <- tibble(Company. = if_else(runif(100) < 0.5, "STL", "Other"),
       Product. = if_else(runif(100) < 0.5, "N24", "Other"),
       MRP = runif(100, 1000, 1500))
```

Which will produce the tibble `feb_raw` which looks like:

```
> feb_raw
# A tibble: 100 x 3
   Company. Product.   MRP
   <chr>    <chr>    <dbl>
 1 STL      Other    1134.
 2 STL      N24      1109.
 3 Other    N24      1258.
 4 Other    Other    1134.
 5 STL      Other    1091.
 6 Other    N24      1259.
 7 Other    N24      1281.
 8 Other    N24      1065.
 9 Other    Other    1128.
10 STL      Other    1359.
# ... with 90 more rows
```

Here's the correct filter code as noted in Chris's answer:

```
filter(feb_raw, Company. == "STL" &
                Product. == "N24" &
                MRP <= 1360 &
                MRP >= 1150)
```

Which returns what appears to be your desired result:

```
# A tibble: 7 x 3
  Company. Product.   MRP
  <chr>    <chr>    <dbl>
1 STL      N24      1154.
2 STL      N24      1255.
3 STL      N24      1255.
4 STL      N24      1187.
5 STL      N24      1214.
6 STL      N24      1235.
7 STL      N24      1302.
```